# DIfferent HANDLE results for Named Mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Is it normal for `OpenMutex()` to always return a different handle address? The documentation says it returns the `HANDLE` if successful, `NULL` otherwise.

Every instance of OpenMutex returns a different handle...

m_logMutex is defined as `static HANDLE`.

```
    m_logMutex = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, LOGMUTEX);
    if(m_logMutex == NULL) {
        m_logMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, LOGMUTEX); 
    }
```

Also, since this is **named**, why even have a static HANDLE? This is part of a program that can file thousands of transactions from different processes into the same db. I'm finding that my static HANDLE gets changed to a different handle and caused `WAIT_FAILED` errors

Comment: Yes, it's okay. It is possible to even have 2+ handles to the same kernel object simultaneously (see `DuplicateHandle` API).

Comment: Related: Maybe i've been in the Unix world to long, but as I recall you can simply `CreateMutex`, and you can "know" whether it opened a previously opened mutex of the same name by checking `GetLastError()` for `E_ALREADY_EXISTS` if knowing whether you were the one who created it or not is important. In other words, the `if OpenMutex()` logic here seems unnecessary.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I noticed the same behavior with `CreateMutex()`, but I was concerned with seeing new handles each time.

Comment: @WhozCraig: In theory, yes. Again there's a subtle difference between knowing that the mutex exists and actually getting the mutex. There are some edge cases where this difference plays a role, e.g. some time lags with the OS cleanup of orphaned handles after hard-terminating processes. The MSDN sample regarding that topic is misleading (to say the least) and has been for many years, BTW.

Comment: Handles are not file descriptors. FD's are sequential while Windows handles (to kernel objects) are just pointers into the kernel memory.

Comment: I do notice that my static global HANDLE CreateMutex returned NULL if a secondary process calls it. I had to move the whole HANDLE to the function and call OpenMutex to get a non-NULL handle.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference in here: The call does not return **the** handle. The call returns **a** handle.

As long as the handle retrieved allows you to do what you asked for (i.e. security permissions) everything's fine. Just don't assume anything about the handles that's not clearly documented.

> Also, since this is named, why even have a static HANDLE? This is part of a program that can file thousands of transactions from different processes into the same db.

The `static` refers to your variable. It is not a property of the handle itself.

> I'm finding that my static HANDLE gets changed to a different handle and caused WAIT_FAILED errors

As long as you don't close the handle (and maybe properly `DuplicateHandle()` where needed) this should not happen. If you `CloseHandle()` it, it will of course become invalid. If you pass handles between parts of your program, you should be careful with the ownership of the handle, for the same reason. And if you pass handles between processes, calling `DuplicateHandle()` is mandatory.

Other than that, it's pretty simple. No black magic involved with handles.

Comment: I did notice that my static global HANDLE 'CreateMutex' call returned NULL if a secondary process calls it (by including the .cpp). I had to move the whole HANDLE to the transaction function and call 'OpenMutex/CreateMutex' to get a non-NULL handle. I just commented out the global static Mutex and my tests look promising.